# How to create a simple MessageBox alternative (WPF)

Tags: c#, wpf, messagebox

I've created a simple MessageBox alternative using this code:
Messagebox Window:

```
    public partial class Messagebox
{
    public Messagebox()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    public void Show(string title, string text)
    {
        Show(); //this shows the actual Messagebox window when this
                //method is called. You could replace this with:
                //new Messagebox().Show();
        titleE.Content = title;
        textE.Content = text;
    }
}
```

that goes in another Window (i've called Messagebox as it's close to MessageBox)
This is to actually call it in the MainWindow or somewhere else:

```
    public Messagebox Messagebox = new Messagebox();
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Messagebox.Show("ooooo", "text here");
    }
```

I've made the program open the Messagebox after initialize components as it's a simple way to test if it works or not.
Here's the result: 
[The actual Messagebox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/13tHQ.png)

I was wondering if there is a way to improve this? e.g, making the messagebox width/height change as more text is added (im not sure how to do that yet)
and adding buttons that can be added programmatically and allowing them to do something.

Comment: Assuming the container of the message box is using a control which only takes up the size needed to house the content it should shrink/grow as needed. I believe StackPanels automatically size to fit contents.

Comment: You should create properties and set them in the `MainWindow`. 
For functionality you could use `DelegateCommands`.  
When you want to create it totally "free" then you should have a `Grid` as a Property and create the `Grid` as wanted in your `MainWindow` and then just add the `Grid` as a child to that `Messagebox`

Comment: This question is better suited for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/